# adding special search functionality to list view

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, hidden

I have created a list view in android and I want to add edit text above the list and when the user enter text the list will be filtered according to user input
But  i want the list to be hidden at the first time 
and when the user inters 3 chars the data appears
can anyone tell me please if there is a way to filter the list adapter in android ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. What form of data do you have in your adapter ? The steps are basically:

1. Set an adapter with no data or no adapter to your listview
2. When the users enter 3 chars, filter your raw data.
3. Set the data of your adapter to the filtered data.
4. Ask your adapter to draw itself or add the adapter to your listview.

Comment: thank you for answering 
am beginner so your comment could be difficult for me
i am going to explain more :
am trying to display  a large number of strings  from xml (16.000) 
so i get a black screen 
that's why  i want it to be hidden at the first time